# ionic serve: cannot start local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to start a simple blank project with ionic:

```
ionic start firstProject blank --v2
```

but when I cd into the firstProject folder and execute: ionic serve, I get this:

```
> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /home/user/Workspace/firstProject
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
```

and nothing else, when it should build the application. I do not know what is going on.

ionic info:

- Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.2.2
- ios-deploy version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: Not installed
- OS: Linux 4.8
- Node Version: v6.10.0
- Xcode version: Not installed

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: It just serves. Have you opened localhost:8100?

Comment: Yes. It did not work. I just tried to follow the [getting started](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) guide from ionic.

Comment: Explain **how** it doesn't work. Please also consider adding the verbose option.

Comment: Running 'ionic serve...' should build the starter application, start a local server and open the default browser in localhost:8100 (default). The process just get stuck there, before building the application. In that way I think it did not work. I wonder if there may be some issue with my version of node.